# Physics without time

Tags: time, reversibility, arrow-of-time

The structure of physical law as we generally recognize it today is firmly held together by the existence of time. Although physical laws can both predict and retrodict (reversible time does not break the laws but entropy seems to police the direction in real life), are we able to go further and in some manner entirely divorce time from physical law?

Have there been attempts to do this, and if so what are the main roadblocks that prevented a reformulation?

Is it just that a time-free physics is not compatible nor useful with beings that depend on memory?

Comment: I think this is a very interesting question, but probably too speculative, or philosophical even , for this site.

Comment: @PhotonicBoom Definitely not too philosophical. This is a well posed question which will admit objective answers.

Comment: @DanielSank Lets hope so, I'm looking forward to an answer actually.

Comment: In what way would allegedly "time-free" physics be different? I mean, the fact that things can happen in the same place but not coincide would have to be reflected somehow, right?

Comment: Also, there have been B-decay measurements in which T-symmetry is explicitly violated (and of course all CP-violating measurements are assumed to violate T, as well). And while that's pretty esoteric does it throw a wrench into the whole idea if there are time-non-reversablilties at the level of basic law?

Comment: @dmckee: I also think that saying that time is time-reversal symmetric is entirely different from doing without time entirely.  A universe that obeys parity symmetry is hardly one in which space does not exist.

Comment: If one describes dynamics in 3D, there has to be some parametrization of that dynamics. Whether or not you call it time/pathlength/entropy is up to you.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_End_of_Time_(book), http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Unreality_of_Time, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternalism_(philosophy_of_time). Pretty philosophical, I believe. Therefore: http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/time/.

Comment: Hi have you read Barbour "the end of time",in which he pretty much deals, imo, with the question you are asking and you may or may not agree with his arguments. To me this always remains a philophical question by default as I have never seen a comprehensive answer to the question "what do you mean by the word time".

Comment: I'm surprised this hasn't been mentioned yet - [Wheeler-DeWitt equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheeler%E2%80%93DeWitt_equation). "The Wheeler–DeWitt equation is an attempt to combine mathematically the ideas of quantum mechanics and general relativity, a step toward a theory of quantum gravity. In this approach, time plays no role in the equation, leading to the problem of time". The role time plays in physics seems to be buried in the difficulties with combining QM and GR due to their differences in treatment of time.

Comment: Carlo Rovelli worked on stuff like this, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carlo_Rovelli#Physics_without_time

Answer (score 4):

I once read of a science fiction scenario where  on a planet the distance from a specific center was time. Life in that format progressed in height  from the center, grew contours of certain height  and became flat at death. The consciousness of those entities had time defined by their changes but humans just saw a completed contoured landscape unchanging in human terms.

We, humans, define time by changes  .  The three dimensional contours in our environment, described by dx/dy, dy/dz,dz/dx etc  change values . These changes force us to define time. The sun motion,  day and night these are geometrical changes in contours that would be invariant if t=constant. In contrast to the hypothetical planet above our fourth dimension, time, has more complicated algebra but the concept is the same.

Physics without time would just be three dimensional geometry, invariant, and it is evident that just three dimensional geometry does not describe even the simplest phenomena we observe, a falling apple for example.

Answer (score 3):

No complete formulation of physics without time is possible. To be physical, a formulation must explain and predict the observable universe, of which time is a fundamental feature. In a timeless formulation, no quantities can change and no events can cause or be caused. Since we overwhelmingly find that quantities do change and events have causal relations to each other, a purely timeless formulation is unphysical.

Comment: But when we say "observable universe" doesn't that intimately connect the universe to beings with memory and the same attribute that we have designed into our instruments to also sense the universe? How can we trust that memory is a part of physical nature as well as biological or rather psychological nature?

Comment: The answer is scientific idealism. Throughout conscious life, we receive a constant stream of subjective information. In that stream we observe patterns. Those patterns are what we call the physical world. A physical theory only has content insofar as it predicts subjective (mental) events, of which time and memory are critical features. A theory that claims to be complete but has no relation to mental life can't even be said to be wrong; it is an empty collection of symbols without referents.

Comment: @docscience: "Observable" has a technical meaning that doesn't require intelligence. At the quantum level, observation means interaction. Our eyes observe the sun because photons from the sun hit electrons around atoms in our retina. At that point it is already "observed". That the interaction further cause the electron to climb its valence band causing electrical activity that triggers further chemical activity in our nervous system to ultimately signal our brain is not necessary for the quantum effect of detecting the photon to happen.

Comment: Suppose I tell you that that is all wrong, that I have a new theory of physics that doesn't feature photons, electrons, mass, charge, or even space. Instead, it relates quantities I call pineapple, strawberry, and watermelon through a set of mathematically consistent equations. If you tell me it doesn't produce any observable results, I retort that you define observation in terms of a bunch of objects like photons that don't exist. My theory predicts observations in terms of events like changes in the pineapple value. How would you reply?

Comment: @user27118 I'd ask whether you're theory more adequately explains my garage or the dragon inside. http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/The_Dragon_in_My_Garage

Answer (score 2):

We know particles that exists outside of time: Photons, travelling at the speed of light, see their path (and their lifetime) relativistically contracted to a point (and an instant of no duration). It must obviously be mathematically possible to describe what happens to a photon in its own rest frame.

We just do not know how: Just changing our frame of reference leads to the problem that everything on the photon's path appears at the same point, the only one ever seen by the photon (in its rest frame). We cannot squeeze enough information into a singular point for this to work the way relativity suggest should work, with the known laws of physics.

If we could discover how the known laws of physics (or perhaps our Lorentz transform, or perhaps our notion of spacetime) need to be extended to describe known physics from the point of view of a photon, we would have a description outside time, and hence at least superficially free of time.

Comment: "obviously"? I don't agree that a photon must have a rest frame, nor that if it did it would have the properties you describe...

Comment: A particle's rest frame is a concept, a mathematical idea if you like. If it does not exist yet, we can invent it. I'm not using any properties other than what follows from (the limit of) a Lorentz transform for that speed.

Comment: this is actually a very interesting point to bring up, where can I read more on this?